# Error in Vim with autocmd: No matching autocommands

Tags: vim, clang, code-completion

I'm using the Vim plugin **clang_complete** and I want to update the compilation errors in the QuickFix window whenever I save the file. So as the doc says, I must call the function `g:ClangUpdateQuickFix()`.

The thing is that the next autocmd gives me the next message whenever it is executed despite it seems to work:

**No matching autocommands**

The autocmd I use is:

`autocmd BufWritePost *.c,*.cpp,*.cxx,*.cc call g:ClangUpdateQuickFix()`

What is the meaning of that message?

Answer (score 2):

The displayed message come from clang_complete itself. Some vim plugins (not clang_complete) are reparsing the quickfix window whenever it changes. Fortunately, vim provide an autocmd for that: QuickFixCmdPost, so these plugins are using this to reparse the quickfix messages.

In clang_complete, since we're modifiying the quickfix window and we don't want to break existing plugins, we need to trigger this autocmd manually. What you get is the **No matching autocommands** message when you don't use those plugins.